# Modificar productos Woocommerce por columnas en móvil

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

necesito modificar los productos insertados en una página de Wordpress mediante shortcodes para poder visualizar más de un producto (2 productos) en la misma fila.

[image: Shortcodes pagina Wordpress]

He añadido un código CSS adicional pero no consigo hacerlo bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi web [ebregrow.com](http://ebregrow.com)

Este es el código que he intentado:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .products {
     width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `products` suele ser un `ul` y cada producto un `li` con clase `product` asi q el `width:50%` debería ir en el `li` o en `.product` ( sin s final )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he podido resolver esto con este código:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```